# How to modify the above line if pattern matches in sun solaris

Tags: solaris

could anyone help me modify the line before a matched pattern in sun solaris i.e search for a pattern and replace the line above with some other text.
eg:
In the input file :

```
<td>
Completed
</td>
```

output needed:

```
<td bgcolor = 'green'>
Completed
</td>
```

the pattern "Completed" should be searched first and then replace the just above line with some other text.
The following are the commands i have used and failed to get the result,

1. `sed 's/<td>\nCompleted/<td>Completed/' exp12.html > sample.html`
2. `sed 's/<td>$Completed/<td>Completed/' exp12.html > sample.html`
3. `tr '\n' '*' exp12.html > sample.html`

   through this, all the text comes to a single line and then have used this
   `sed '/<td>*Completed*/<td bgcolor = 'green'>*Completed*/' exp12.html > sample.html`

Please provide me with a sun solaris command that can fetch the above mentioned output.

Comment: perl is available on the host ?

Comment: No.There is no perl in host.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. We worked out a solution for this problem. following are the commands that worked for us. 1). sed '/<td>/{N;s/\n//g;}' exp12.html > sample.html. this command find the pattern <td>. N bring the next line after the pattern into the pattern space. s/\n//g will subtitute the new line charcter in the pattern space with nothing. the output would be <td>Completed. 2)sed 's/<td>Completed/<td bgcolor="green">Completed/g' sample.html this command will subtitue the pattern. Once again thanks for all your help guys.